# React display props on table from props.object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in react where I pass so data in a prop:

```
<Mycomponent names={[{name: 'peter'},{name: 'pan'}]} />
```

Then I have a component which has a table and where I want to display the data in a

Here is the component

```
import React from 'react';

const Mycomponent = (props) => <div>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{ props.names }</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>;

export default Mycomponent;
```

How do I loop and display each name in a `<tr><td>{props.names.name}</td></tr>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tbody>
  {
     props.names.map( ({name}, i) => <tr key={i}><td>{ name }</td></tr> )
  }
</tbody>
```

will iterate over all of props.names and return a tr for each

Comment: it should be either `<td>{name.name}</td>` or `map(({ name }) => <td>{ name }</td>`

Comment: Yes, didnt actually look to see how names were stored, edited.

Comment: also assign `key` to each `tr` :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Fine, but I wont enjoy it.

Comment: also close the tbody tag :)

Comment: @SpeedOfRound its not a fun game for me also, just correcting your errors.

Comment: I'm getting: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Comment: I set it up in a sandbox and it works, see if you can figure out where you differ:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n9yl4pvwnp